# Remove text using regex

Tags: groovy, regexp-replace

```
<Proposer>
        <Proposer_Type Val="P" Desc="Private"/>
</Proposer>
```

Im using groovy and regex to replace the text
I have text like that, i want to replace text to this

```
<Proposer>
        Proposer_Type;P;Private
</Proposer>
```

CUrrently im using replace simple text:

```
text = text.replace(" Val=", ";")
text= text.replace(" Desc=", ";")
text = text.replace("\"", "")
```

Can anyone help please

Comment: Apart from wondering why you'd want to replace valid XML with something that doesn't appear to be valid anything, I'm also wondering how anyone would help you when you've provided no context, not even a programming language.

Comment: Sorry @TangentiallyPerpendicular , my missed, i just update language

Comment: @ĐứcThắngNguyễn, do you really need regex to solve this strange task?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parser instead of regex

```
import groovy.xml.XmlSlurper
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder

def input = '''<Proposer>
        <Proposer_Type Val="P" Desc="Private"/>
</Proposer>'''

String xmlOutput = new XmlSlurper().parseText(input).with { xml ->
   new MarkupBuilder().Proposer(
       xml.children().collect {
           // For each child in the input, make a string
           "${it.name()}:${it.@Val.text()}:${it.@Desc.text()}"
       }.join('\n')
   )
}
```

But I'm not 100% sure that's what you want...